# getElemenstByTag returning null inside facebook page plugin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, iframe

Is there any Error in the code ? or How should I get desired output ?

My aim is to do this

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("IMG").style = "filter:invert(100%);";
```

The Entire Code is given Below

```
<iframe onload="frameload()" lazy="true" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts block-popups allow-forms" class='viewport-iframe' id='iframe1' src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTroll.Malayalam%2Fposts%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&colorscheme=&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=false&appId" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  function frameload(){
   alert(document.getElementById('iframe1'));
   alert(document.getElementById('iframe1').getElementsByTagName("img"));
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to use `document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")`, then why do you call `document.getElementById('iframe1').getElementsByTagName("img")`?

Comment: @VLAZ I was trying different types of changes in code

Comment: @VLAZ Which is the right one ?

Comment: You CAN NOT reach into an iframe that has its content loaded from a different domain, with scripting from your page, the Same Origin Policy prevents that.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any way to make all images inverted in colour inside an IFRAME

Comment: No. Besides the parameters the plugin provides, you have no control over its content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting iframe successfully than change your code like this. Add your attributes in iframe tag

```
<iframe onload="frameload()" id='iframe1'></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript">
   function frameload(){
         var tags = [...document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")];
         tags.forEach((el)=>{el.style="filter:invert(100%);"});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: But Bro,Still the image in Iframe is not inverted

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ ! use following, working for me `[...document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")]`

Comment: What's the use of that 3 dots (...)

Comment: var tags = [document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img")];
 alert(tags);
Iam not getting any alert box, which means null value,right ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ ! 3 dots (...) are called Spread Operator. Sorry, can't explain here, google it

Comment: Instead of using alert use `console.log(tags)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237161/discussion-between-abu-bakar-and-simpleguy).